# Change Ball border color

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So when drawing a ball in Canvas Html5 I notice there is a default border around it that is black with a thickness of about maybe 1? Do you know how to change the color? I already know how to change the color using CanvasContext.lineWidth.

Comment: can you show us the code you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the strokeStyle property of the context:

```
context.strokeStyle = '#ffffff'; // Gives a white border
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I'll mark this as the answer since you were first.

Answer (score 0):

To change the colour of the stroke, set `ctx.strokeStyle` to a CSS colour name.